# How can I turn my gravel driveway into a green driveway?

Tags: weed-control, ground-cover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What ground cover would be best for my old stone driveway?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-ground-cover-would-be-best-for-my-old-stone-driveway)

Any ideas for what I could either seed directly onto gravel or plant for reasonable quick growth (ground cover).  This is an area which gets a little bit of car passage but mostly people.  I'm in southwest france (reasonably mild).  We are tired of adding hundreds of euros of gravel each year, and the weeds just get through anyways, so why not turn the whole thing green?

Comment: Hi, I believe the answer to this question also addresses your question (only difference being stone vs. gravel): http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3667/109. Please let me know if it does and we'll mark this a duplicate

Comment: @yoda  Thank you, I think that helps !  Does it need to be planted a bit all over and then hope it spreads?

Comment: That's usually how it's done. You can buy a mat or a flat of creeping thyme and tear of little pieces from it and plant it about 12-18 inches (30-45 cms) apart and in time, they'll spread to cover the entire area. You may have to confirm with the nursery or read the label to see how vigorously it spreads — depending on that you might have to increase/decrease the spacing (usually, it's mentioned). I wouldn't recommend planting them too close or seeding them like grass, because then they'll end up fighting with each other for space, sunlight and other resources and not have the desired effect.